# Sonarqube - How do I produce a summary sheet

Tags: pdf, sonarqube, summary

I have produced a code analysis of around 40 java classes, I am not a fan of reading one by one. I have read such documentation as [the documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Reporting). When I add the jar file from the [governance](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Governance+plugin) my server crashes after 1-2 seconds once it's running.

What am I missing here? Does this version of governance not worth (Which I assume to have the most up to date sonarqube as I downloaded it recently)

Answer (score 0):

Governance is a paid feature available in [Enterprise Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/). You need to have a license to be able to run it.

Comment: Is there any other way to produce some sort of summary sheet?